# Python speedtest app without using speedtest library

Tags: python, python-requests, speed-test

I am targeting to make an speedtest application, but without using any functions such as .download, .upload or .ping, also speedtest library not allowed. I am thinking to get ping by shell commands but i do not know others. I am doing this project on aws cloud server, I am using ec2 just for information.

The output should be like:
download:
upload:
ping:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from views import views
import requests
import time
import speedtest

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix = "/views")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/measure', methods=['POST'])
def measure():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ########BEGIN CODE Between these sections will be deleted because .download etc functions
        ########are not all allowed
        st = speedtest.Speedtest()
        download_speed = st.download() / 10**6  # Convert to Mbps
        upload_speed = st.upload() / 10**6  # Convert to Mbps
        ping = st.results.ping
        ########END CODE
    return render_template('measure.html', download_speed=download_speed, upload_speed=upload_speed, ping=ping)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

I am very open for any correction or any idea for this problem. We have to make an speedtest application without using functions as mentioned before and we do not use speedtest library. I am not sure but requests may be used for this problem. (but not sure)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to subjective responses are generally not a good fit for this site, since there generally is not a single correct answer but a range of opinions based on different approaches. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and [mre] then edit your post.